# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

The answers provided in other questions don't seem to work. This code is throwing the error:

```
print("You have taken %s damage!" % int(v) - int(w) + int(armour))
```

And the full code around that area:

```
z =  random.randint(1, 6)
print("The die rolled %s." % z)
w = z + y
print("Your total is %s." % w)
time.sleep(1)
print("The enemy's total Strength is %s." % eStrength)
time.sleep(1)
z = random.randint(1, 6)
print("The enemy's die rolled %s." % z)
v = z + eStrength
print("The enemy's total is %s." % v)
time.sleep(1)
if w < v:
       print("The enemy has won this attack!")
       print("You have taken %s damage!" % int(v) - int(w) + int(armour))
       oldHp = hp
       hp = int(oldHp) - int(v) - int(w) + int(armour)
       print("Your Health is now %s" % hp)
       if hp == 0 or hp < 0:
              time.sleep(1)
              print("You have died. GAME OVER.")
              exit
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it a TypeError to use an arithmetic expression in %-style print formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209111/why-is-it-a-typeerror-to-use-an-arithmetic-expression-in-style-print-formattin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your usage of old style print formatting. `%`. The line `print("You have taken %s damage!" % int(v) - int(w) + int(armour))` is replacing `%s` with `int(v)` and then trying to subtract `int(w)`.

The fix (if you want to use old style formatting, which you shouldn't) is do replace
`print("You have taken %s damage!" % int(v) - int(w) + int(armour))`
with
`print("You have taken %s damage!" % (int(v) - int(w) + int(armour)))`

This makes it compute the equation before trying to format it.

Having said that, the proper way to do it would be to replace
`print("You have taken %s damage!" % int(v) - int(w) + int(armour))`
with
`print("You have taken {0} damage!".format(int(v) - int(w) + int(armour)))`

Comment: @armymutt22 Glad I could help. Please do consider using the new style string formatting. It's much more powerful and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operand is no longer recommended, and they have [begun the deprecation process as of Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101). You'll want to use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html) in a construct like this:

```
print("The die rolled {}.".format(z))
```

The issue is one of precendence, though:

```
>>> print("Test %s" % (int(1) - int(2)))
Test -1
```

By using format this will become much more clear (precedence is implicit in the parameter passing, rather than using an inline operator):

```
print("Test {}".format(int(1) - int(2)))
```

You can do a lot with `format()`, such as:

```
print("The armor deflected {} out of {} damage!".format(armor_value, damage))
```

Or:

```
print("The armor deflected {armor} out of {damage} damage!"
      .format(damage=damage, armor=armor_value))
```

Or:

```
print("{1}, {2} and {3} died!".format(char1.name, char2.name, char3.name))
```

Comment: It's absolutely still used, just not recommended.

Comment: Ok, yes, it is available, but not the best practice anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I add parentheses:

```
print("You have taken %s damage!" % (v - w + z))
```

I changed the "armour" variable to just an `int` because I did not have it.