# Why is it a TypeError to use an arithmetic expression in %-style print formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I tried to input a float number and output a simple result using two methods:

```
t = float(input())
print('{:.2f}'.format(1.0 - 0.95 ** t))
print('%.2f' % 1.0 - 0.95 ** t)
```

The first method worked but a TypeError occurred in the second one:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Even if it might make sense for `%` to have lower precedence when used as the string formatting operator, precedence is determined by the parser without regard to the semantic meaning of the operator. `%` has higher precedence than `-`, just as it does when `%` is the numerical modulo operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line: `print('%.2f' % 1.0 - 0.95 ** t)`

Python is trying to do `'%.2f' % 1.0` first, then subtracting `0.95 ** t` from the result. That's a problem because the first term is a string and the second one is a float.

Use parentheses to control the order of operations. That line should be:

```
print('%.2f' % (1.0 - 0.95 ** t))
```